# Verifcar se uma porta COM está conectada ou não

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

É possível via linha de código verificar se uma porta COM está conectada ou não ?

Análisem:
Tenho um program **PDV**(Ponto de Venda) onde o mesmo tem a integração com a SiTef, através de um **PinPad**(máquina de cartão) e pra que o mesmo funcione, o **PinPad** tem que estar conectado em uma porta COM.

PinPad Conectado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, afim de deixar mais robusto o sistema e evitar `exception` ao tentar realizar o procedimento com o **PinPad**, caso o mesmo não esteja conectado, gostaria de verificar via linha de código se está ou não conectado e atribuir essa verificação nos respectivos eventos que fazem a integração.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível saber se o conector está plugado, mas na maioria dos equipamentos da pra monitorar o sinal de CTS que é usado para controle de fluxo de dados.

```
if(port.CtsEnable)
{
}
```

Se o fabricante do hardware não estiver utilizando esse port, então outra opção seria enviar pela porta um comando de solicitação de status e verificar uma possível resposta.
Vale lembrar que se o dispositivo estiver desconectado, terá o mesmo efeito que quando desconectado.